# Using asyncio.run, is it safe to run multiple times?

Tags: python-asyncio

The documentation for asyncio.run states:

> This function always creates a new event loop and closes it at the end.
> It should be used as a main entry point for asyncio programs, and should
> ideally only be called once.

But it does not say why.  I have a non-async program that needs to invoke something async.  Can I just use `asyncio.run` every time I get to the async portion, or is this unsafe/wrong?

In my case, I have several `async` coroutines I want to `gather` and run in parallel to completion.  When they are all completed, I want move on with my synchronous code.

```
async my_task(url):
    # request some urls or whatever

integration_tasks = [my_task(url1), my_task(url2)]

async def gather_tasks(*integration_tasks):
    return await asyncio.gather(*integration_tasks)


def complete_integrations(*integration_tasks):
    return asyncio.run(gather_tasks(*integration_tasks))

print(complete_integrations(*integration_tasks))
```

Comment: It really depends on what you're trying to accomplish. You can call `run` as many times as you want, but each call will use a brand new event loop, so if a particular call ends before all of its tasks end, they aren't going to resume running with the new event loop.

Comment: @dirn I have several `async` methods I want to gather.  I updated message to describe above.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to reuse `integration_tasks` (the coroutines will already have been awaited), but you should be able to call `complete_integrations` as many times as you'd like (with new coroutines).

Comment: asyncio is not parallel processing. Says so in the docs.

Comment: @jwal meaning what?

Comment: @Scott you say _in parallel to completion_, this is not what happens. What happens is that the co-routines run co-operatively until completion, returning to the event loop when awaiting slow responses as they complete their tasks. So your question is odd. Two events loops running co-routines is a complicated version of one event loop. If you want parallel, run in a separate processes on a computer with a separate CPU core, not a separate thread (see https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock), not a separate event loop.

Comment: Ah i see.  I don't want two event loops running in parallel.  I want one event loop running several coroutines cooperatively within an otherwise-synchronous program.  Then I want to do that again, later.

Answer (score 9):

## Can I use `asyncio.run()` to run coroutines multiple times?

This actually is an interesting and very important question.

As a [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run) of asyncio (python3.9) says:

> This function always creates a new event loop and closes it at the end. It should be used as a main entry point for asyncio programs, and should **ideally** only be called once.

It does not prohibit calling it multiple times. And moreover, an old way of calling coroutines from synchronous code, which was:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(coroutine)
```

Is now deprecated because of `get_event_loop()` method, which [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.get_event_loop) says:

> Consider also using the asyncio.run() function instead of using lower level functions to manually create and close an event loop.

> Deprecated since version 3.10: Deprecation warning is emitted if there is no running event loop. In future Python releases, this function will be an alias of get_running_loop().

So in future releases it will not spawn new event loop if already running one is not present! Docs are proposing usage of `asyncio.run()` if You want to automatically spawn new loop if there is no new one.

There is a good reason for such decision. Even if You have an event loop and You will successfully use it to execute coroutines, there is few more things You must remember to do:

- closing an event loop
- consuming unconsumed generators (most important in case of failed coroutines)
- ...probably more, which I do not even attempt to refer here

What is exactly needed to be done to properly finalize event loop You can read in [this source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/asyncio/runners.py).

Managing an event loop manually (if there is no running one) is a subtle procedure, and it is better to not doing that, *unless one know what he is doing*.

So Yes, I think that proper way of runing async function from synchronous code is calling `asyncio.run()`. But it is only suitable from a **fully synchronous application**. If there is already running event loop, it will probably fail (not tested). In such case, just `await` it or use `get_runing_loop().run_untilcomplete(coro)`.

And for such synchronous apps, using `asyncio.run()` it is safe way and actually **the only safe way** of doing this, and it **can** be invoked multiple times.

The reason docs says that You **should** call it only once is that usually there is one single entrypoint to whole asynchronous application. It simplifies things and actually improves performance, because setting thins up for an event loop also takes some time. But if there is no single loop available in Your application, You should use multiple calls to `asyncio.run()` to run coroutines multiple times.

## Is there is any performance gain?

Beside discussing multiple calls to `asyncio.run()`, I want to address one more concern. In comments, @jwal says:

> asyncio is not parallel processing. Says so in the docs. [...] If you want parallel, run in a separate processes on a computer with a separate CPU core, not a separate thread, not a separate event loop.

Suggesting that asyncio is not suitable for parallel processing, which can be misunderstood and misleading to a conclusion, that it will not result in a performance gain, **which is not always true**. Moreover it is usually false!

So, any time You can delegate a job to an external process (not only a python process, it can be a database worker process, http call, ideally any TCP socket call) You can utilize a performance gain using asyncio. In huge majority of cases, when You are using a library which exposes async interface, the author of that library made an effort to eventually *await* for a result from a network/socket/process call. While response from **such socket is not ready, event loop is completely free to do any other tasks**. If loop has more than one such tasks, *it will gain a performance*.

A canonical example of such case is making a calls to a HTTP endpoints. At some point, there *will* be a network call, so python thread is free to do other work while awaiting for a data to appear on a TCP socket buffer. I have an example!

The example uses httpx library to compare performance of doing multiple calls to a [OpenWeatherMap API](https://openweathermap.org/current). There are two functions:

- `get_weather_async()`
- `get_weather_sync()`

The first one does 8 request to an http API, but schedules those request to
run *cooperatively* (not concurrently!) on an event loop using `asyncio.gather()`.

The second one performs 8 synchronous request in sequence.

To call the asynchronous function, I am actually using `asyncio.run()` method. And moreover, I am using `timeit` module to perform such call to `asyncio.run()` 4 times. So in a single python application, `asyncio.run()` was called 4 times, just to challenge my previous considerations.

```
from time import time
import httpx
import asyncio
import timeit
from random import uniform


class AsyncWeatherApi:
    def __init__(
        self, base_url: str = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5"
    ) -> None:

        self.client: httpx.AsyncClient = httpx.AsyncClient(base_url=base_url)

    async def weather(self, lat: float, lon: float, app_id: str) -> dict:
        response = await self.client.get(
            "/weather",
            params={
                "lat": lat,
                "lon": lon,
                "appid": app_id,
                "units": "metric",
            },
        )

        response.raise_for_status()

        return response.json()


class SyncWeatherApi:
    def __init__(
        self, base_url: str = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5"
    ) -> None:

        self.client: httpx.Client = httpx.Client(base_url=base_url)

    def weather(self, lat: float, lon: float, app_id: str) -> dict:
        response = self.client.get(
            "/weather",
            params={
                "lat": lat,
                "lon": lon,
                "appid": app_id,
                "units": "metric",
            },
        )

        response.raise_for_status()

        return response.json()


def get_random_locations() -> list[tuple[float, float]]:
    """generate 8 random locations in +/-europe"""
    return [(uniform(45.6, 52.3), uniform(-2.3, 29.4)) for _ in range(8)]


async def get_weather_async(locations: list[tuple[float, float]]):
    api = AsyncWeatherApi()
    return await asyncio.gather(
        *[api.weather(lat, lon, api_key) for lat, lon in locations]
    )


def get_weather_sync(locations: list[tuple[float, float]]):
    api = SyncWeatherApi()
    return [api.weather(lat, lon, api_key) for lat, lon in locations]


api_key = "secret"


def time_async_job(repeat: int = 1):
    locations = get_random_locations()

    def run():
        return asyncio.run(get_weather_async(locations))

    duration = timeit.Timer(run).timeit(repeat)
    print(
        f"[ASYNC] In {duration}s: done {len(locations)} API calls, all"
        f" repeated {repeat} times"
    )


def time_sync_job(repeat: int = 1):
    locations = get_random_locations()

    def run():
        return get_weather_sync(locations)

    duration = timeit.Timer(run).timeit(repeat)
    print(
        f"[SYNC] In {duration}s: done {len(locations)} API calls, all repeated"
        f" {repeat} times"
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    time_sync_job(4)
    time_async_job(4)
```

At the end, a comparison of performance was printed. It says:

```
[SYNC] In 5.5580058859995916s: done 8 API calls, all repeated 4 times
[ASYNC] In 2.865574334995472s: done 8 API calls, all repeated 4 times
```

Those 4 repetitions was just to show that You can safely run a `asyncio.run()` multiple times. It had actualy destructive impact on measuring performance of asynchronous http calls, because all 32 request was actually run in four synchronous batches of 8 asynchronous tasks. Just to compare performance of one batch of 32 request:

```
[SYNC] In 4.373898585996358s: done 32 API calls, all repeated 1 times
[ASYNC] In 1.5169846520002466s: done 32 API calls, all repeated 1 times
```

So yes, it can, and usually will result in performance gain, if only proper async library is used (if library exposes an async API, it usually does it intentianally, knowing that there will be a network call somewhere).